# How to use read function in perl?

Tags: perl, variables

Here is the part of old perl script I struggle with.
The variable `$h` suddenly defined inside of `if` and I cannot figure out what it means.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);

if (open(LIST,"/proc/partitions"))
{
    while (<LIST>)
    {
        my @a = split(/\s+/); 
        print "@a\n";
        if (looks_like_number($a[3]) && $a[3] > 100000000)
        {
            if (open(IN, "/dev/$a[4]"))
            {
                my $h;
                if (read(IN, $h, 4) == 4 && $h eq 'EFI')
                {
                    print "/dev/$a[4]\n";
                }

                close(IN);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's actually a part of the code.

Anyway it's running well, but in my knowledge, nothing is saved to the variable `$h` and just defined.

Is it related with `looks_like_number`?

Can you tell me what I miss?

Comment: Note: `$h` is not good name for the variable, perhaps `$buf` or `$fsType` would be more appropriate

Comment: Note: you have an opportunity to use [open](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open) in accordance with current documentation

Comment: When you say `split /\s+/`, you most likely mean `split ' '`. Which can be shortened to just `split`. Read `perldoc -f split` for more info.

Comment: When you say "suddenly defined", did you mean that you wrote some other code, which you for some reason decided not to show us, that shows `$h` being defined, containing a value other than `undef`? Perhaps you should elaborate on that part and show the relevant code.

Comment: Also, of course `$h` is defined inside the `if` clause. You have a condition `$h eq 'EFI'`, which means that inside the if-clause `$h` will be equal to the string `"EFI"`. I suspect you do not know what "defined" means in Perl terms. Maybe you mean "declared"? Or "in scope"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's written to by the [`read`](https://perldoc.pl/functions/read) function:

> **read FILEHANDLE,SCALAR,LENGTH**
>
> Attempts to read LENGTH *characters* of data into variable SCALAR from the specified FILEHANDLE. Returns the number of characters actually read, `0` at end of file, or undef if there was an error (in the latter case `$!` is also set). SCALAR will be grown or shrunk so that the last character actually read is the last character of the scalar after the read.